# Differential Mode EMI Filter Design for DC Power Input Noises

Tags: filter, emc, low-pass, emi-filtering, passive-filter

[image]

https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/productdata/8796777775134/ENFH0008.pdf
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/murata-electronics/BNX022-01L/1825573

Hi everyone, I try to understand this circuit for my project. I want to use DM LC filter which BNX022-01L.When I looked at datasheet of filter, I missed to understand that how it works? Are L1 and L2 diff mode inductor? C1,C2 and L3 are LP filter? Why they don't use any value for components?

If any one explain that clearly I will really appreciated. Also, I can't find LTspice library for this component for simulating.How can I simulate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L1, L2 and C1 form a differential LP filter. L3 and C2 form a single ended filter. C2 is a feed through capacitor.
The values are in section 3 of the datasheet.
You don't really care about the individual part values, only about the insertion loss at the specific frequency, assuming the product complies with your voltage and power requirements.
You can derive the inductance value from the insertion loss figure at a specific frequency.

Comment: Well, this filter needs external capacitor like Cx?

Comment: The purpose of such devices is to provide a compact solution to EMI/RFI problems. You can implement it with discrete components, but it will probably take more place and more SMT placements, both of which cost money.